# Deletion in B Plus Tree Korth Pseucode

Tags: database, algorithm, pseudocode

The pseudo code given in the Database Systems Concept by Korth is the following.
[Pseucode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY6s2.png)

Consider that we have the following tree with order = 5

```
                         [7.0]
       [3.0, 5.0]                      [9.0, 11.0, 13.0]
 <Lead Nodes Here>                       <Lead Nodes Here>
```

Now image that we are at level 2 and in the function delete_entry([3.0, 5.0], 3.0, Pointer to Child). Now as per the algorithm we delete 3.0, so now we are left with [5.0] and [9.0, 11.0, 13.0]. Looking at the first marked if condition we see that these nodes can be merged as (1+3) <= (order - 1) therefore 4 keys can fit in one node. But since they are not a leaf node therefore the second marked line in the code will execute and apart from merging these two nodes it will also insert 7 in them. Therefore giving us a node with number of keys = 5, which violates the condition that number of keys in non leaf node should be <= order -1.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please try to avoid using pictures and to write the pseudocode (better if simplified) on your question.